# Counting Working days between two timestamps

Tags: function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that stored all dates and whether the date is a holiday/weekend/workingdays or not.
To be able to count the working days between 2 different date I have this query:

```
 SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN is_workday = 1 AND is_holiday = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
             ABS(SUM(CASE 
                          WHEN start_date = date.date AND (is_workday = 0 OR is_holiday = 1) THEN 1 
                          WHEN end_date = date.date AND (is_workday = 0 OR is_holiday = 1) THEN -1 ELSE 0 END)) 
                          +
            IFF(ABS(SUM(CASE 
                            WHEN start_date = date.date AND (is_workday = 0 OR is_holiday = 1) THEN 1 
                            WHEN end_date = date.date AND (is_workday = 0 OR is_holiday = 1) THEN -1 ELSE 0 END)) = 0, 0, -1) 
       AS duration
      FROM "XXX"."ZZZ"."DATE" DATE
```

the second and third condition in the query is for taking care of the cases where the one or both of the dates are holiday/weekend

Now I want to create a function that from now on I can call the function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "XXX"."PUBLIC".working_days(start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
   returns int 
   as
   $$
     SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN is_workday = 1 AND is_holiday = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
             ABS(SUM(CASE 
                          WHEN start_date = date.date AND (is_workday = 0 OR is_holiday = 1) THEN 1 
                          WHEN end_date = date.date AND (is_workday = 0 OR is_holiday = 1) THEN -1 ELSE 0 END)) 
                          +
            IFF(ABS(SUM(CASE 
                            WHEN start_date = date.date AND (is_workday = 0 OR is_holiday = 1) THEN 1 
                            WHEN end_date = date.date AND (is_workday = 0 OR is_holiday = 1) THEN -1 ELSE 0 END)) = 0, 0, -1) 
       AS duration
      FROM "XXX"."ZZZ"."DATE" DATE
      WHERE date.date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
   $$
```

Now the function is working very well if I give some date ( hard code the dates) to it but as soon as I want to use the function in a table (For example call the function for calculating duration between order date and delivery date in  `order_table` ) then I am receiving this error:
`SQL compilation error: Unsupported sub-query type cannot be evaluated`

I already read snowflake documentation on "user-defined-table-function" but I was not able to fix the issue. Is there a way that I can fix this? the problem is coming from these parts:

```
start_date = date.date
end_date= date.date
```

Comment: Please show us the code that is raising the error.

Comment: @GMB It is as I wrote in the question:

`
SELECT id,
"XXX"."PUBLIC".working_days (day_1,day_2) AS nr_days
FROM table_1
`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with a simpler `working_days()` function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION working_days(start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
RETURNS int
AS 
$$
SELECT 1 + end_date - start_date  - (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM holidays 
  WHERE date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
  AND (is_holiday OR NOT is_workday)
)
$$
;
```

Let's test it. First we need a table with all the holidays and non-working days:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE holidays
AS 
SELECT '2020-01-03' date, 1 is_holiday, 0 is_workday
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-01-15', 0 is_holiday, 1 is_workday
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-01-18', 0 is_holiday, 0 is_workday
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-03-15', 0 is_holiday, 1 is_workday
;
```

And a table with starting and end dates:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE sample1
AS 
SELECT '2020-01-01' date1, '2020-02-01' date2
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01'
UNION ALL SELECT '2020-01-03', '2020-01-03'
;
```

And now we can test it:

```sql
SELECT date1, date2, working_days(date1, date2)
FROM sample1
```

The results as expected:

[image]